# Meaning of the inverse of a Markov transition matrix

Tags: markov-chains

Consider a basic Markov process where vector $x$ at time $t$ switches states with a transition matrix $A$, so that:
$$
x(t+1) = A x(t).
$$

Assume that A is invertible, we can write the above as:
$$
A^{-1}x(t+1) = x(t)
$$

What is the meaning of $A^{-1}$? Does it have any special properties?

Comment: One property that might be interesting to point out is that when $A$ is invertible, we can reverse time.

Comment: Thanks, I realise now the question is a bit silly.